# PHPSpreadsheet - How do create text that is red colored?

Tags: php, sql, phpspreadsheet

I use the next line to color a cell red.:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('O'.$i)->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('O'.$i)->getFill()->getStartColor()->setARGB('FF2911');
```

But i don't get it fixed to color the text red and not the cell.
I tryed using what they saying here [link](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/) , but for some reasen i don't get it to work.

I also tryed this, but nothing changes.:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('O'.$i)->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color::COLOR_RED);
```

Can somebody help me please.

Comment: Try to change getFill to getFont

Comment: if i try that the script fails

Comment: Solved! Stupid from my side, on the end of my code i make everything one color.